# MySQL- 1 row with same date in same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
| test_dates          | alb_results | chl_results |
| 1994-05-09 00:00:00 |    45       |    NULL     |
| 1994-05-09 00:00:00 |    NULL     |   0.65      |
```

As you can see, the data have the same date and same time. I need a MySQL statement that will output something like this.

```
    | test_dates          | alb_results | chl_results |
    | 1994-05-09 00:00:00 |    45       |   0.65      |
```

I need to make it one row for all the data with the same date and same time. I know that it is much easier if I have two tables by using `Join` statement. But this time I have only one table.

Please help me. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT test_dates,
       MAX(alb_results),
       MAX(chl_results)
    FROM Tbl
    GROUP BY test_dates;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT w.test_dates  AS test_dates
     , w.alb_results AS alb_results
     , z.chl_results AS chl_results
  FROM table AS w
  JOIN table AS z ON z.test_dates = w.test_dates
 WHERE w.alb_results IS NOT NULL
   AND z.chl_results IS NOT NULL
;
```

`WHERE` clause here is used to restrict cartesian production to the single row for each date.